# performance of prototype vs passing object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, es6-class

I have a class that needs a reference to a property from it's parent. I would like to know if it is better to pass in the property to the constructor of the child class and set it as a new property of the child class, or while in the parent class add it as a prototype of the child class.

implemenatation A:

```
// parent-class.js

let childClass = require('childClass.js');

class foo {

    constructor() {
        this.initChild = new childClass(this.superCoolMethod);
    }

    superCoolMethod() {
         return 'this method does super cool stuff and the child needs it';
    }

}

// child-class.js

class bar {
    constructor(superCoolMethod) {
        this.superCoolMethod = superCoolMethod;
    }

    callCoolMethod() {
        this.superCoolMethod();
    }

}
```

implemenatation B:

```
// parent-class.js

let childClass = require('childClass.js');

class foo {
    constructor() {
        this.childClass.prototype.superCoolMethod = superCoolMethod;
        this.initChild = new childClass(this.superCoolMethod);
    }

    superCoolMethod() {
         return 'this method does super cool stuff and the child needs it';
    }
}

// child-class.js

class bar {

    callCoolMethod() {
        this.superCoolMethod();
    }

}
```

Which implementation would be more performant and are there any better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: What's your goal is assigning a method from one instance to an object of another instance? (And beware using `super` in that case, it may not do what you expect.)

Comment: my goal would be to have the child class be able to call a method from the parent class

Comment: Okay. Note that the way you're doing it, when it does, `this` will not be set correctly. I would tend to lean toward having a class that acts like an interface, and passing an instance of that into `child` rather than just a method. But in isolation it's hard to tell what design compromises to make.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around exactly what you mean by an interface... I know what interfaces are in terms of TypeScript but as far using that in this case I'm not totally sure how that would work @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is JavaScript, duck typing is sufficient. I'd pass the parent instance in rather than just its method, and then have the child call the method via that parent instance, so `this` is correct.

Comment: ok, makes sense. thank you. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134699/discussion-between-trickpatty-and-t-j-crowder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which implementation would be more performant...

It doesn't matter. It's a massively bad idea for class `foo` to reach out and change the prototype of class `childClass`. (But the instance property would be ***very-very-very-slightly*** faster, because the property lookup stops at the instance, rather than not finding it at the instance and then needing to look to the prototype. In the real world, the odds of it making any noticeable difference at all are near zero.)

Remember: That prototype is used by all other `childClass` instances, even those completely unrelated to `foo` code. The link between instance and its prototype is a *link*; instances don't get a *copy* of their prototype. So for example:

```js
class Example {
};

const e = new Example();

console.log(e.foo);   // undefined

Example.prototype.foo = 42;

console.log(e.foo);   // 42
```

> and are there any better ways to achieve this?

Set it as a property on the instance (e.g., implementation A or similar).

Comment: when you say "Set it as a property on the instance." do you mean this? :
`this.initChild.superCoolMethod = this.superCoolMethod;`

Comment: @trickpatty: I mean implementation A (or yeah, you could just assign it after constructing like that). But note the question on the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would set it as a property. It is the way it makes sense. If you change the prototype, you will have the added method in all subsequent `new childClass()` objects. That may not be desired behavior.